# Text outside a List view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I’m trying to put text along the side of a `List` view that lines up with its individual item. Is there any way to do this? I tried `.offset()` but the text seems to just disappear after reaching the edge of the list.

[Trying to do something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5VJc.jpg)

Comment: @cedricbahirwe I mean, it's just a `List` with text inside. The image I included has a `Spacer` on the side, but it doesn't have to be there. All I'm asking about is moving text outside of the `List`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it uses `InsetGroupedListStyle()`

Comment: Not 100% from description and picture, but think having a look at a few article on "swiftui alignment guides", e.g. https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/  might be the relevant SwiftUI tech needed, if not it'll point where to look next.